# Erro na compilação do kernel no ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, x86, kernel

Estou tentando compilar o kernel 3.2.91 no Ubuntu e quando executo o comando make ocorre esse erro:

```
scripts/Makefile.build:305: recipe for target 'arch/x86/kvm/vmx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/kvm/vmx.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:441: recipe for target 'arch/x86/kvm' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/kvm] Error 2
Makefile:946: recipe for target 'arch/x86' failed
make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
```

Já mexi em todas configurações do kvm no menuconfig e não consigo descobrir o que poderia estar causando este erro e como consertá-lo.

Comment: poste o seu código completo, assim fica mais fácil o entendimento da pergunta

Comment: Não tem código, apenas o .config da configuração do kernel
Após configurar o menuconfig, eu executo o seguinte comando no terminal:
root@beatriz-VirtualBox:/usr/src/linux# make

E ele dá esse erro, início do erro:
arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c: In function ‘vmx_vcpu_run’:
arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c:6182:18: error: invalid character ' ' in raw string delimiter
   "push %%"R"dx; push %%"R"bp;"
                  ^
arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c:6182:3: error: stray ‘R’ in program
   "push %%"R"dx; push %%"R"bp;"

Comment: Tente remover a virtualizacao no make menuconfig

Comment: Tirar a virtualização faz o kernel compilar, porém não consigo bootar o kernel depois, acho que a retirada da virtualização está prejudicando isso